Reverse-engineer Bubendorff CLEP21 remote controller
TLDR; I have a Bubendorff shutter system, whereas each shutter has its own remote controller. I am trying to clone the remote controllers, to build a single system for shutter control. There are three open questions to break the protocol, I'd appreciate any help you can provide.
1. Hardware
Remote controllers operate at the standard 433.92 MHz and have 2 ICs: uC/ASIC (Zilog 5087/CLEP21/2D6BM) and EEPROM (Microchip 24LC01B).
Unfortunately, I have not been able to find any information on the Zilog IC, hence my assumption that it is an ASIC specifically designed for this purpose, based on their Z80 CPUs.
There are only 2 buttons available on the controller: down & up. There does not seem to be a way to pair additional remote controllers with the existing shutter.
2. Tests
I have 3 unique remote controllers, each has a serial number printed in decimal on the enclosure backside. I tapped on the I2C bus between ASIC and EEPROM and also monitored the emitted serial bitstream (i.e., the signal that modulates the 433.92 MHz signal).
The test was performed as follows:

Power cycle the remote controller,
Record I2C transaction and emitted bitstream for 256 button-down actions.

Both these steps were repeated for the button-up action, and tests were done on all 3 remote controllers.
2.1. I2C transaction
It seems that the ASIC never updates EEPROM, it only reads its registers.
On power-up, it starts by reading a sequence of 19 bytes from 0x40..0x52:
====================================================================
            40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 4A 4B 4C 4D 4E 4F 50 51 52
--------------------------------------------------------------------
REMOTE 1    0C 29 71 70 F5 2A 7B C3 8D 20 1C 0D 8E 02 00 01 00 2C 0B
REMOTE 2    0C 29 71 70 F5 2A EF 2D 3C 0D 1C 62 D2 02 00 01 00 2C 0B
REMOTE 3    0C 29 71 70 F5 2A F9 6C BB 16 1C 4D 84 02 00 01 00 2C 0B
====================================================================

Unique bytes are in the range 0x46..0x4C, with the exception of 0x4A.
On every action (button-down or -up), the ASIC first reads 4 bytes from the EEPROM. It then transmits the register address (2 bytes) and the obfuscated register value (4 bytes), as it will be shown later.
2.2. Serial bitstream
On every action, after reading 4 bytes from the EEPROM, the ASIC emits serial bitstream at about 1.2 kHz: (i) start condition (36 ms HIGH followed by 12 ms LOW), and (ii) 165 data bits. This whole sequence is immediately repeated once more.

Since this is an asynchronous transmission (no clock), each data frame consists of a start bit, 8 data bits, an invert bit, and a stop bit, i.e., 11 bits per frame in total. This means that 165 bits translate into 15 data bytes. The invert bit requires special attention - at first I thought this was a parity check, but it seems its only function is for bit-wise invert of data bytes when equal to 1. I am not sure what is the purpose of the invert bit other than to obfuscate the bitstream.
3. Protocol decoding
Here is an excerpt of 4 decoded actions:
=======================================================================================================================
EEPROM MESSAGES            EEPROM SIMPLIFIED          EMITTED BITSTREAM                               DATA INVERT BITS
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
A0 B0 A1 B1 A2 B2 A3 B3    A01-23  B0 B1 B2 B3        S0 S1 S2 S3 S4 S5 S6 S7 S8 S9 SA SB SC SD SE
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# REMOTE 1: BUTTON-DOWN
0D 9B 14 28 2D ED 3F 55 -> [D4 DF] 9B 28 ED 55        A6 1C 0D 8E 00 01 D4 DF A3 F9 EF 01 01 B7 46    [001010010100111]
0A 10 19 32 29 AC 33 B5 -> [A9 93] 10 32 AC B5        A6 1C 0D 8E 00 01 A9 93 00 16 4D 5E 01 63 8D    [001010001001000]
05 ED 13 14 20 6C 3B EA -> [53 0B] ED 14 6C EA        A6 1C 0D 8E 00 01 53 0B CA 1B 63 C5 01 F1 5A    [001010000000110]
0A 10 16 8D 21 C3 36 A8 -> [A6 16] 10 8D C3 A8        A6 1C 0D 8E 00 01 A6 16 F1 6C 24 F4 01 87 A7    [001010000011101]
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# REMOTE 1: BUTTON-UP
0D 9B 14 28 2D ED 3F 55 -> [D4 DF] 9B 28 ED 55        A6 1C 0D 8E 00 01 D4 DF A3 F9 EF 01 00 77 87    [001010010100110]
0A 10 19 32 29 AC 33 B5 -> [A9 93] 10 32 AC B5        A6 1C 0D 8E 00 01 A9 93 00 16 4D 5E 00 A3 4C    [001010001001001]
05 ED 13 14 20 6C 3B EA -> [53 0B] ED 14 6C EA        A6 1C 0D 8E 00 01 53 0B CA 1B 63 C5 00 31 9B    [001010000000100]
0A 10 16 8D 21 C3 36 A8 -> [A6 16] 10 8D C3 A8        A6 1C 0D 8E 00 01 A6 16 F1 6C 24 F4 00 47 66    [001010000011100]
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# REMOTE 2: BUTTON-DOWN
0D 34 14 CF 2D C5 3F 01 -> [D4 DF] 34 CF C5 01        A6 1C 62 D2 00 01 D4 DF E7 09 ED 0F 01 73 2D    [001010010000110]
0A 0B 19 BA 29 13 33 F8 -> [A9 93] 0B BA 13 F8        A6 1C 62 D2 00 01 A9 93 69 3D 80 2C 01 BA 60    [001010000110110]
05 6D 13 EA 20 1B 3B E4 -> [53 0B] 6D EA 1B E4        A6 1C 62 D2 00 01 53 0B 51 75 42 A8 01 34 52    [001010001110100]
0A 0B 16 3C 21 2D 36 B7 -> [A6 16] 0B 3C 2D B7        A6 1C 62 D2 00 01 A6 16 98 D7 07 7A 01 6B 46    [001010001111110]
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# REMOTE 2: BUTTON-UP
0D 34 14 CF 2D C5 3F 01 -> [D4 DF] 34 CF C5 01        A6 1C 62 D2 00 01 D4 DF E7 09 ED 0F 00 B3 EC    [001010010000111]
0A 0B 19 BA 29 13 33 F8 -> [A9 93] 0B BA 13 F8        A6 1C 62 D2 00 01 A9 93 69 3D 80 2C 00 7A A1    [001010000110110]
05 6D 13 EA 20 1B 3B E4 -> [53 0B] 6D EA 1B E4        A6 1C 62 D2 00 01 53 0B 51 75 42 A8 00 F4 93    [001010001110110]
0A 0B 16 3C 21 2D 36 B7 -> [A6 16] 0B 3C 2D B7        A6 1C 62 D2 00 01 A6 16 98 D7 07 7A 00 AB 87    [001010001111110]
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# REMOTE 3: BUTTON-DOWN
0D 43 14 28 2D F2 3F D9 -> [D4 DF] 43 28 F2 D9        A6 1C 4D 84 00 01 D4 DF 88 9F F9 4B 01 7C DF    [000010011100110]
0A 0B 19 EE 29 37 33 93 -> [A9 93] 0B EE 37 93        A6 1C 4D 84 00 01 A9 93 7B 50 9F 8A 01 F9 F6    [000010000000110]
05 AD 13 14 20 36 3B 84 -> [53 0B] AD 14 36 84        A6 1C 4D 84 00 01 53 0B 58 55 5A 17 01 48 0D    [000010001000101]
0A 0B 16 BB 21 6C 36 F4 -> [A6 16] 0B BB 6C F4        A6 1C 4D 84 00 01 A6 16 A3 96 F2 FE 01 2A BC    [000010000001100]
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# REMOTE 3: BUTTON-UP
0D 43 14 28 2D F2 3F D9 -> [D4 DF] 43 28 F2 D9        A6 1C 4D 84 00 01 D4 DF 88 9F F9 4B 00 BC 1E    [000010011100110]
0A 0B 19 EE 29 37 33 93 -> [A9 93] 0B EE 37 93        A6 1C 4D 84 00 01 A9 93 7B 50 9F 8A 00 39 37    [000010000000100]
05 AD 13 14 20 36 3B 84 -> [53 0B] AD 14 36 84        A6 1C 4D 84 00 01 53 0B 58 55 5A 17 00 88 CC    [000010001000100]
0A 0B 16 BB 21 6C 36 F4 -> [A6 16] 0B BB 6C F4        A6 1C 4D 84 00 01 A6 16 A3 96 F2 FE 00 EA 7D    [000010000001110]
=======================================================================================================================

3.1. EEPROM messages
Bytes (i) A0..A3 are register addresses set by the ASIC, and (ii) B0..B3 are rolling codes stored in the EEPROM. Note that high-order nibbles of address bytes never change, and low-order nibbles form a 2-byte register address emitted in the bitstream (see the EEPROM SIMPLIFIED column).
The rolling codes are different for 3 remote controllers, but the sequence of register addresses is always the same. This brings us to the first mystery:
Mystery #1: What is the logic behind the register address sequence?
Given below is the sequence of the first 256 condensed 2-byte register addresses:
EA79, D4DF, A993, 530B, A616, 4C01, 3029, 8165, 02E7, 1738, 2E70, 73AD, E75A, CE99, 9D1F, 7426,
E84C, D0B5, A147, 42A3, 8546, 0AA1, 1542, 2A84, 5508, AA10, 540D, A81A, 4049, 0212, 1090, 092D,
125A, 24B4, 4968, 92D0, 258D, 4B1A, 9634, 2C45, 588A, B114, 6205, 8839, 105F, 417C, 82F8, 05DD,
1774, 2EE8, 5DD0, 776D, EEDA, DD99, BB1F, EC26, D861, B0EF, 61F3, C3E6, 1FDE, FEF0, DD7B, EB36,
D641, ACAF, 5973, B2E6, CBC2, 97A9, 2F7F, 5EFE, 7BD5, F7AA, EF79, DEDF, BD93, 7B0B, F616, EC01,
D82F, B073, C196, 8301, 062F, 18BC, 3178, 62F0, 8BED, 17F7, 2FEE, FEBA, EA0B, A136, 4241, 8482,
0929, 1252, 24A4, 4948, 9290, 250D, 4A1A, 9434, 2845, 508A, A114, 4205, 0839, 1072, 41C8, 8390,
070D, 1C34, 3868, 70D0, C36D, 86F7, 0DC3, 1B86, 370C, 6E18, DC30, B84D, 70B7, E16E, C2F1, 85CF,
0BB3, 1766, 2ECC, 5D98, BB30, 764D, EC9A, D919, C826, 9061, 41DE, 83BC, 0755, 3AA8, 7550, AAF7,
55C3, AB86, 5721, AE42, 5CA9, B952, 7289, E512, CA09, 943F, 2853, 50A6, A14C, 42B5, 856A, 0AF9,
2BE4, 57C8, AF90, BE1A, F832, E0BF, C153, 828B, 0A76, 14EC, 29D8, 53B0, 4EED, 9DDA, 3B99, 7732,
EE64, DCE5, E7C6, CFA1, 3EF3, 7DE6, FBCC, EF47, DEA3, BD6B, F5F6, EBC1, D7AF, AF73, 5ECB, BD96,
7B01, EC29, D87F, B0D3, 618B, C316, 8601, 0C2F, 185E, 30BC, 6178, C2F0, 85CD, 0BB7, 176E, 2EDC,
5DB8, BB70, 76CD, ED9A, DB19, B061, C1DE, 8391, 070F, 1C3C, 3878, 70F0, C3ED, 87F7, 0FC3, 7E18,
FC30, E143, C2AB, 15B6, 2B6C, 56D8, ADB0, 5B4D, B69A, 6D19, DA32, B449, 68BF, D17E, A2D1, 458F,
8B1E, 2C22, 5844, B088, 613D, C27A, 84D9, 099F, 133E, 267C, 4CF8, 33CD, 679A, CF34, 9E45, 3CA7

3.2. Serial bitstream
Here are my observations about the serial bitstream:

S0 - not sure where it comes from and what is its purpose, but it is always 0xA6
S1..S3 correspond to unique bytes at 0x4A..0x4C in the EEPROM
S4..S5 correspond to non-unique bytes at 0x4E..0x4F in the EEPROM
S6..S7 is the condensed 2-byte register address (see the EEPROM SIMPLIFIED column)
S8..SB is the obfuscated rolling code
SC is the command: 0x01 for button-down and 0x00 for button-up
SD..SE is the 16-bit CRC calculated with the CRC-16/ARC polynomial.

Mystery #2: How to calculate the emitted rolling code from the one in EEPROM?
I feel this mystery is crucial for cracking the protocol!
Mystery #3: What is the logic behind the "data bit inversion"?
For this last mystery, I have to do some more tests to check if it is deterministic. It does not seem to be consistent for button-down and -up actions.
I appreciate any help/idea you might have! :)

It's an interesting problem but tricky to follow ... perhaps you could write a little pseudocode to explain a little more clearly.  I can't see how to use the 9th bit, for example, where does that come from?  Or what B1-B4 are.

Yes, I am aware. I'll create a GitHub project where I'll explain everything in a bit more detail.
